# Java GUI paint picture on labels

Tags: java, image, user-interface, label, panel

I want to add a picture that will be in the panel and also on labels but I don't know how to do that.

> my code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
    {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        panel.add(label);
    }



mainPanel.add(panel);
frame.add(mainPanel);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

My Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Ssy.png

What I want to make:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLPqF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use components do to this job, then you're going to need to do some juggling with the layout managers.  Because of it's flexibility, I would use `GridBagLayout`, in fact, I'm pretty sure it's the only inbuilt layout that will allow you to do something like this...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new GamePane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        public GamePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    GridPane gridPane;
                    if (y == 9) {
                        if (x == 9) {
                            gridPane = new GridPane(1, 1, 1, 1);
                        } else {
                            gridPane = new GridPane(1, 1, 1, 0);
                        }
                    } else if (x == 9) {
                        gridPane = new GridPane(1, 1, 0, 1);
                    } else {
                        gridPane = new GridPane(1, 1, 0, 0);
                    }
                    gbc.gridx = x;
                    gbc.gridy = y;
                    add(gridPane, gbc);
                }
            }

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridheight = 4;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(new ShipPane(1, 4), gbc, 0);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridwidth = 3;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new ShipPane(3, 1), gbc, 0);
        }

    }

    public class Configuration {
        public static int GRID_SIZE = 50;
    }

    public class GridPane extends JPanel {

        public GridPane(int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
            setBorder(new MatteBorder(top, left, bottom, right, Color.DARK_GRAY));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(Configuration.GRID_SIZE, Configuration.GRID_SIZE);
        }

    }

    public class ShipPane extends JPanel {

        private int gridWidth, gridHeight;

        public ShipPane(int gridWidth, int gridHeight) {
            this.gridWidth = gridWidth;
            this.gridHeight = gridHeight;
            setOpaque(false);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(Configuration.GRID_SIZE * gridWidth, Configuration.GRID_SIZE * gridHeight);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I'm just using a panel, but without much work, you could add a `JLabel` to the `ShipPane`

Now, having said that.  I think I would approach this problem from an entirely "custom painting" route

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()` and  `public void run() ` does? because it works without it too

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, all UI interactions/modifications must be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. The `EventQueue.invokeLater` ensures that the creation of the UI is done within this context.  Strictly speaking, until the frame is realised on (sized/made visible), it's not yet connected to the EDT, but the rules are so murky, I just dump it all in the EDT to be sure

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to use JLabel.setIcon

```
JLabel l = ...;
l.setIcon(myIcon);
```

You can make an Icon from an Image using `ImageIcon`.

You can get an image by loading it from disk/url, or by creating your own by creating a BufferedImage and drawing to its Graphics object.

Comment: Doesn't it put the picture on one label?
I want the picture to be in the panel on the labels like in this picture:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLPqF.png

Comment: @moshe: then you may need to either use a JLayeredPane or draw your drawing on the GUI's glass pane.

Comment: Can you show example please @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @moshe: I have neither the time nor the energy at this time, but if you search this site, you'll see plenty of examples by me and others, including MadProgrammer, Camickr, ControlAltDel, and others.